# How do I get text to show on screen?

Tags: c, osdev, vesa

I'm working on an operating system, and I recently switched to VESA Graphics for more pixels and colors to work with. I'm trying to draw text to screen, though no matter what color value I put in, I can't see anything show up. I know there isn't an issue with the bitmap because I've used it before, and I can't see any issues with the VESA Graphics setup. Before, I was using VGA Graphics, and all I had to do for that was input an integer value corresponding to a color table online for 8-bit color. Here I'll show some of my attempts:

```
static void render(int c0, int c1) {
    draw_rect(0,0,SCREEN_WIDTH,SCREEN_HEIGHT, 0);                                   //black?
    draw_string("Hello, reader. This is written text.", 100, 180, 0xffffff);        //white? 
    draw_string("If this is displayed, my code works.", 100+c0, 100+c1, 16777215);  //white?
}
```

In the end, all this uses the `screen_set` function shown here:

```
void screen_set(u32 color,int x,int y) {
    u32 physical_address = modeInfo->PhysBasePtr;
    physical_address += y * modeInfo->LinBytesPerScanLine;
    physical_address += x * bytesPerPixel;

    _sbuffers[physical_address] = color;
}
```

As seen above, I've tried a few different forms of color input, though nothing seems to work. Here I'll leave my `kernel.c` and a [link to my GitHub](https://github.com/Subwaey/KaiOS/tree/main/src):

```
/*
TODO:

-Filesystem
-Mouse Inputs
-Simple GUI
-3d Viewer
-Maybe Link Downloader and Viewer
*/

#define NULL ((void*)0)
#define true    1
#define false   0
typedef unsigned char uint8_t;
typedef unsigned char u8;
typedef unsigned short uint16_t;
typedef unsigned int u32;
typedef u32 size_t;
typedef unsigned long phys_bytes;
#define SCREEN_WIDTH (int)(modeInfo->XResolution)
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT (int)(modeInfo->YResolution)
#define BPP 32
#define SCREEN_SIZE (SCREEN_WIDTH * SCREEN_HEIGHT)
#define FPS 30
#define PIT_HERTZ 1193131.666
#define CLOCK_HIT (int)(PIT_HERTZ/FPS)
#define KEY_LEFT 0x4B
#define KEY_UP 0x48
#define KEY_RIGHT 0x4D
#define KEY_DOWN 0x50

void * malloc(size_t len) {
    static size_t curoff = 0;
    static char space[1 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024];
    void *ptr = NULL;
    if ((curoff + len) < sizeof(space)) {
        ptr = &space[curoff]; curoff += len;
    } return ptr;
}

typedef struct VBE_modeInfo{
/*  Mandatory information for all VBE revisions */
uint16_t ModeAttributes;
uint8_t WinAAttributes;
uint8_t WinBAttributes;
uint16_t WinGranularity;
uint16_t WinSize;
uint16_t WinASegment;
uint16_t WinBSegment;
phys_bytes WinFuncPtr;
uint16_t BytesPerScanLine;
/* Mandatory information for VBE 1.2 and above */

uint16_t XResolution;
uint16_t YResolution;
uint8_t XCharSize;
uint8_t YCharSize;
uint8_t NumberOfPlanes;
uint8_t BitsPerPixel;
uint8_t NumberOfBanks;
uint8_t MemoryModel;
uint8_t BankSize;
uint8_t NumberOfImagePages;
uint8_t Reserved1;
/* Direct Color fields (required for direct/6 and YUV/7 memory models) */

uint8_t RedMaskSize;         /* size of direct color red mask in bits */
uint8_t RedFieldPosition;    /* bit position of lsb of red mask */
uint8_t GreenMaskSize;       /* size of direct color green mask in bits */
uint8_t GreenFieldPosition;  /* bit position of lsb of green mask */
uint8_t BlueMaskSize;        /* size of direct color blue mask in bits */
uint8_t BlueFieldPosition;   /* bit position of lsb of blue mask */
uint8_t RsvdMaskSize;        /* size of direct color reserved mask in bits */
uint8_t RsvdFieldPosition;   /* bit position of lsb of reserved mask */
uint8_t DirectColorModeInfo; /* direct color mode attributes */

/* Mandatory information for VBE 2.0 and above */
phys_bytes PhysBasePtr;
uint8_t Reserved2[4];
uint8_t Reserved3[2];
/* Mandatory information for VBE 3.0 and above */
uint16_t LinBytesPerScanLine;  /* bytes per scan line for linear modes */
uint8_t BnkNumberOfImagePages; /* number of images for banked modes */
uint8_t LinNumberOfImagePages; /* number of images for linear modes */
uint8_t LinRedMaskSize;        /* size of direct color red mask (linear modes) */
uint8_t LinRedFieldPosition;   /* bit position of lsb of red mask (linear modes) */
uint8_t LinGreenMaskSize;      /* size of direct color green mask (linear modes) */
uint8_t LinGreenFieldPosition; /* bit position of lsb of green mask (linear  modes) */
uint8_t LinBlueMaskSize;       /* size of direct color blue mask (linear modes) */
uint8_t LinBlueFieldPosition;  /* bit position of lsb of blue mask (linear modes ) */
uint8_t LinRsvdMaskSize;       /* size of direct color reserved mask (linear modes) */
uint8_t LinRsvdFieldPosition;  /* bit position of lsb of reserved mask (linear modes) */
u32 MaxPixelClock;        /* maximum pixel clock (in Hz) for graphics mode */
uint8_t Reserved4[190];        /* remainder of ModeInfoBlock */
} VBE_modeInfo;

struct VBE_modeInfo *modeInfoPointer;
#define modeInfo modeInfoPointer

#define BUFFER ((u32 *) (modeInfo->PhysBasePtr))

// double buffers
u32 *_sbuffers;
u32 _sback = 0;

static inline void outb(uint16_t port, uint8_t val)
{
    asm volatile ( "outb %0, %1" : : "a"(val), "Nd"(port) );
}

#define bytesPerPixel ((modeInfo->BitsPerPixel + 7) / 8)

void screen_set(u32 color,int x,int y) {
    u32 physical_address = modeInfo->PhysBasePtr;
    physical_address += y * modeInfo->LinBytesPerScanLine;
    physical_address += x * bytesPerPixel;

    _sbuffers[physical_address] = color;
}

static inline uint8_t inb(uint16_t port)
{
    uint8_t ret;
    asm volatile ( "inb %1, %0"
                   : "=a"(ret)
                   : "Nd"(port) );
    return ret;
}

const unsigned char font[128-32][8] = {
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00},   // U+0020 (space)
    { 0x18, 0x3C, 0x3C, 0x18, 0x18, 0x00, 0x18, 0x00},   // U+0021 (!)
    { 0x36, 0x36, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00},   // U+0022 (")
    { 0x36, 0x36, 0x7F, 0x36, 0x7F, 0x36, 0x36, 0x00},   // U+0023 (#)
    { 0x0C, 0x3E, 0x03, 0x1E, 0x30, 0x1F, 0x0C, 0x00},   // U+0024 ($)
    { 0x00, 0x63, 0x33, 0x18, 0x0C, 0x66, 0x63, 0x00},   // U+0025 (%)
    { 0x1C, 0x36, 0x1C, 0x6E, 0x3B, 0x33, 0x6E, 0x00},   // U+0026 (&)
    { 0x06, 0x06, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00},   // U+0027 (')
    { 0x18, 0x0C, 0x06, 0x06, 0x06, 0x0C, 0x18, 0x00},   // U+0028 (()
    { 0x06, 0x0C, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x0C, 0x06, 0x00},   // U+0029 ())
    { 0x00, 0x66, 0x3C, 0xFF, 0x3C, 0x66, 0x00, 0x00},   // U+002A (*)
    { 0x00, 0x0C, 0x0C, 0x3F, 0x0C, 0x0C, 0x00, 0x00},   // U+002B (+)
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0C, 0x0C, 0x06},   // U+002C (,)
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x3F, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00},   // U+002D (-)
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0C, 0x0C, 0x00},   // U+002E (.)
    { 0x60, 0x30, 0x18, 0x0C, 0x06, 0x03, 0x01, 0x00},   // U+002F (/)
    { 0x3E, 0x63, 0x73, 0x7B, 0x6F, 0x67, 0x3E, 0x00},   // U+0030 (0)
    { 0x0C, 0x0E, 0x0C, 0x0C, 0x0C, 0x0C, 0x3F, 0x00},   // U+0031 (1)
    { 0x1E, 0x33, 0x30, 0x1C, 0x06, 0x33, 0x3F, 0x00},   // U+0032 (2)
    { 0x1E, 0x33, 0x30, 0x1C, 0x30, 0x33, 0x1E, 0x00},   // U+0033 (3)
    { 0x38, 0x3C, 0x36, 0x33, 0x7F, 0x30, 0x78, 0x00},   // U+0034 (4)
    { 0x3F, 0x03, 0x1F, 0x30, 0x30, 0x33, 0x1E, 0x00},   // U+0035 (5)
    { 0x1C, 0x06, 0x03, 0x1F, 0x33, 0x33, 0x1E, 0x00},   // U+0036 (6)
    { 0x3F, 0x33, 0x30, 0x18, 0x0C, 0x0C, 0x0C, 0x00},   // U+0037 (7)
    { 0x1E, 0x33, 0x33, 0x1E, 0x33, 0x33, 0x1E, 0x00},   // U+0038 (8)
    { 0x1E, 0x33, 0x33, 0x3E, 0x30, 0x18, 0x0E, 0x00},   // U+0039 (9)
    { 0x00, 0x0C, 0x0C, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0C, 0x0C, 0x00},   // U+003A (:)
    { 0x00, 0x0C, 0x0C, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0C, 0x0C, 0x06},   // U+003B (;)
    { 0x18, 0x0C, 0x06, 0x03, 0x06, 0x0C, 0x18, 0x00},   // U+003C (<)
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x3F, 0x00, 0x00, 0x3F, 0x00, 0x00},   // U+003D (=)
    { 0x06, 0x0C, 0x18, 0x30, 0x18, 0x0C, 0x06, 0x00},   // U+003E (>)
    { 0x1E, 0x33, 0x30, 0x18, 0x0C, 0x00, 0x0C, 0x00},   // U+003F (?)
    { 0x3E, 0x63, 0x7B, 0x7B, 0x7B, 0x03, 0x1E, 0x00},   // U+0040 (@)
    { 0x0C, 0x1E, 0x33, 0x33, 0x3F, 0x33, 0x33, 0x00},   // U+0041 (A)
    { 0x3F, 0x66, 0x66, 0x3E, 0x66, 0x66, 0x3F, 0x00},   // U+0042 (B)
    { 0x3C, 0x66, 0x03, 0x03, 0x03, 0x66, 0x3C, 0x00},   // U+0043 (C)
    { 0x1F, 0x36, 0x66, 0x66, 0x66, 0x36, 0x1F, 0x00},   // U+0044 (D)
    { 0x7F, 0x46, 0x16, 0x1E, 0x16, 0x46, 0x7F, 0x00},   // U+0045 (E)
    { 0x7F, 0x46, 0x16, 0x1E, 0x16, 0x06, 0x0F, 0x00},   // U+0046 (F)
    { 0x3C, 0x66, 0x03, 0x03, 0x73, 0x66, 0x7C, 0x00},   // U+0047 (G)
    { 0x33, 0x33, 0x33, 0x3F, 0x33, 0x33, 0x33, 0x00},   // U+0048 (H)
    { 0x1E, 0x0C, 0x0C, 0x0C, 0x0C, 0x0C, 0x1E, 0x00},   // U+0049 (I)
    { 0x78, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x33, 0x33, 0x1E, 0x00},   // U+004A (J)
    { 0x67, 0x66, 0x36, 0x1E, 0x36, 0x66, 0x67, 0x00},   // U+004B (K)
    { 0x0F, 0x06, 0x06, 0x06, 0x46, 0x66, 0x7F, 0x00},   // U+004C (L)
    { 0x63, 0x77, 0x7F, 0x7F, 0x6B, 0x63, 0x63, 0x00},   // U+004D (M)
    { 0x63, 0x67, 0x6F, 0x7B, 0x73, 0x63, 0x63, 0x00},   // U+004E (N)
    { 0x1C, 0x36, 0x63, 0x63, 0x63, 0x36, 0x1C, 0x00},   // U+004F (O)
    { 0x3F, 0x66, 0x66, 0x3E, 0x06, 0x06, 0x0F, 0x00},   // U+0050 (P)
    { 0x1E, 0x33, 0x33, 0x33, 0x3B, 0x1E, 0x38, 0x00},   // U+0051 (Q)
    { 0x3F, 0x66, 0x66, 0x3E, 0x36, 0x66, 0x67, 0x00},   // U+0052 (R)
    { 0x1E, 0x33, 0x07, 0x0E, 0x38, 0x33, 0x1E, 0x00},   // U+0053 (S)
    { 0x3F, 0x2D, 0x0C, 0x0C, 0x0C, 0x0C, 0x1E, 0x00},   // U+0054 (T)
    { 0x33, 0x33, 0x33, 0x33, 0x33, 0x33, 0x3F, 0x00},   // U+0055 (U)
    { 0x33, 0x33, 0x33, 0x33, 0x33, 0x1E, 0x0C, 0x00},   // U+0056 (V)
    { 0x63, 0x63, 0x63, 0x6B, 0x7F, 0x77, 0x63, 0x00},   // U+0057 (W)
    { 0x63, 0x63, 0x36, 0x1C, 0x1C, 0x36, 0x63, 0x00},   // U+0058 (X)
    { 0x33, 0x33, 0x33, 0x1E, 0x0C, 0x0C, 0x1E, 0x00},   // U+0059 (Y)
    { 0x7F, 0x63, 0x31, 0x18, 0x4C, 0x66, 0x7F, 0x00},   // U+005A (Z)
    { 0x1E, 0x06, 0x06, 0x06, 0x06, 0x06, 0x1E, 0x00},   // U+005B ([)
    { 0x03, 0x06, 0x0C, 0x18, 0x30, 0x60, 0x40, 0x00},   // U+005C (\)
    { 0x1E, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x1E, 0x00},   // U+005D (])
    { 0x08, 0x1C, 0x36, 0x63, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00},   // U+005E (^)
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF},   // U+005F (_)
    { 0x0C, 0x0C, 0x18, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00},   // U+0060 (`)
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x1E, 0x30, 0x3E, 0x33, 0x6E, 0x00},   // U+0061 (a)
    { 0x07, 0x06, 0x06, 0x3E, 0x66, 0x66, 0x3B, 0x00},   // U+0062 (b)
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x1E, 0x33, 0x03, 0x33, 0x1E, 0x00},   // U+0063 (c)
    { 0x38, 0x30, 0x30, 0x3e, 0x33, 0x33, 0x6E, 0x00},   // U+0064 (d)
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x1E, 0x33, 0x3f, 0x03, 0x1E, 0x00},   // U+0065 (e)
    { 0x1C, 0x36, 0x06, 0x0f, 0x06, 0x06, 0x0F, 0x00},   // U+0066 (f)
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x6E, 0x33, 0x33, 0x3E, 0x30, 0x1F},   // U+0067 (g)
    { 0x07, 0x06, 0x36, 0x6E, 0x66, 0x66, 0x67, 0x00},   // U+0068 (h)
    { 0x0C, 0x00, 0x0E, 0x0C, 0x0C, 0x0C, 0x1E, 0x00},   // U+0069 (i)
    { 0x30, 0x00, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x33, 0x33, 0x1E},   // U+006A (j)
    { 0x07, 0x06, 0x66, 0x36, 0x1E, 0x36, 0x67, 0x00},   // U+006B (k)
    { 0x0E, 0x0C, 0x0C, 0x0C, 0x0C, 0x0C, 0x1E, 0x00},   // U+006C (l)
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x33, 0x7F, 0x7F, 0x6B, 0x63, 0x00},   // U+006D (m)
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x1F, 0x33, 0x33, 0x33, 0x33, 0x00},   // U+006E (n)
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x1E, 0x33, 0x33, 0x33, 0x1E, 0x00},   // U+006F (o)
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x3B, 0x66, 0x66, 0x3E, 0x06, 0x0F},   // U+0070 (p)
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x6E, 0x33, 0x33, 0x3E, 0x30, 0x78},   // U+0071 (q)
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x3B, 0x6E, 0x66, 0x06, 0x0F, 0x00},   // U+0072 (r)
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x3E, 0x03, 0x1E, 0x30, 0x1F, 0x00},   // U+0073 (s)
    { 0x08, 0x0C, 0x3E, 0x0C, 0x0C, 0x2C, 0x18, 0x00},   // U+0074 (t)
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x33, 0x33, 0x33, 0x33, 0x6E, 0x00},   // U+0075 (u)
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x33, 0x33, 0x33, 0x1E, 0x0C, 0x00},   // U+0076 (v)
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x63, 0x6B, 0x7F, 0x7F, 0x36, 0x00},   // U+0077 (w)
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x63, 0x36, 0x1C, 0x36, 0x63, 0x00},   // U+0078 (x)
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x33, 0x33, 0x33, 0x3E, 0x30, 0x1F},   // U+0079 (y)
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x3F, 0x19, 0x0C, 0x26, 0x3F, 0x00},   // U+007A (z)
    { 0x38, 0x0C, 0x0C, 0x07, 0x0C, 0x0C, 0x38, 0x00},   // U+007B ({)
    { 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x00, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x00},   // U+007C (|)
    { 0x07, 0x0C, 0x0C, 0x38, 0x0C, 0x0C, 0x07, 0x00},   // U+007D (})
    { 0x6E, 0x3B, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00},   // U+007E (~)
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00}    // U+007F
};

static inline void *memcpy(void *dst, const void *src, size_t n)
{
    u8 *d = (u8*)dst;
    const u8 *s = (const u8*)src;

    while (n-- > 0) {
        *d++ = *s++;
    }

    return d;
}

void screen_swap() {
    memcpy(BUFFER, _sbuffers, SCREEN_SIZE);
}

unsigned read_pit(void) {
    unsigned count = 0;

    // al = channel in bits 6 and 7, remaining bits clear
    outb(0x43,0b0000000);

    count = inb(0x40);          // Low byte
    count |= inb(0x40)<<8;      // High byte

    return count;
}

void draw_char(char c, int x, int y, u32 color)
{
    const unsigned char *glyph = font[(int)c-32];

    for(int cy=0;cy<8;cy++){
        for(int cx=0;cx<8;cx++){
            if(((int)glyph[cy]&(1<<cx))==(1<<cx)){
                screen_set(color,x+cx,y+cy);
            }
        }
    }
}

void draw_string(const char * s, int x, int y, u32 color) {
    int i = 0;
    while(s[i] != false) {
        draw_char(s[i],x+(i*8),y,color);
        i++;
    }
}

void draw_rect(int pos_x, int pos_y, int w, int h, u32 color) {
    for(int y = 0; y<h; y++) {
        for(int x = 0; x<w; x++) {
            screen_set(color,x+pos_x,y+pos_y);
        }
    }
}

static void render(int c0, int c1) {
    draw_rect(0,0,SCREEN_WIDTH,SCREEN_HEIGHT, 0);
    draw_string("Hello, reader. This is written text.", 100, 180, 0xffffff);
    draw_string("If this is displayed, my code works.", 100+c0, 100+c1, 16777215);
}

void main(struct VBE_modeInfo *vbe) {
   modeInfoPointer = vbe;

    _sbuffers = malloc(sizeof(u32) * SCREEN_SIZE);

    int clock = 0;
    int incC1 = 0;
    int incC0 = 0;
    while(true) {
        uint16_t scancode = (uint16_t) inb(0x60);
        clock++;
        if(read_pit()!= 0 && clock == CLOCK_HIT) {
            if(scancode == KEY_LEFT) {
                incC0--;
            }else if(scancode == KEY_RIGHT) {
                incC0++;
            }
            if(scancode == KEY_DOWN) {
                incC1++;
            }else if(scancode == KEY_UP) {
                incC1--;
            }
            clock = 0;
            render(incC0,incC1);
            screen_swap();
        }
    }

    return;
}
```

---

**EDIT:**

As per request, here is the code for drawing a pixel in `VGA` Graphics Mode:

```
void draw_pixel(int pos_x, int pos_y, unsigned char colour)
{
    unsigned char* location = (unsigned char*)0xA0000 + 320 * pos_y + pos_x;
    *location = colour;
}
```

Comment: Questions to answer ... What system are you using? `qemu`? `qemu -vga std`? What is the FB pixel format? 1-bit monochrome? 4-bit palettized? 8-bit palletized? 16-bit color? 24-bit true color? What is the screen resolution (e.g. 1024x768)? What is the exact _pixel_ format (e.g. `1 bit unused|5 bits red|5 bits green|5 bits blue` for 16-bit color)? You define `BUFFER` as `u32 *`, so is this: `8 bit red|8 bit green|8 bit blue|8 bit alpha`? If using `qemu`, you should be able use `gdb`, breakpoint on `main`, then do: `p *vbe` to see the contents of the `VBE_modeInfo` struct. Post that?

Comment: In `boot.asm`, you are using `int 0x10`. (1) ax=4F01 to get VBE info (2) ax=4F02 to set the mode. But, the info you get in (1) is for the _old_ mode/format and _not_ the one you set in (2). You may want to reverse the steps: Set the mode (4F02) and then get the mode (4F01).

Comment: Also, in `boot.asm`, at `start_protected_mode:`, the `eax` value you save/use is _not_ a pointer to `modeInfo` [AFAICT].  At that point, you probably want something like `lea edi,modeInfo` with whatever `add/sub` you need to account for changes to protected mode so `main` gets the correct protected mode pointer.

Comment: Look at qemu gdb doc: https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~dahlin/Classes/439/ref/qemu-gdb-reference.html and qemu monitor doc: https://www.qemu.org/docs/master/system/monitor.html for ways to debug.

Comment: Okay, so responding to your comments in order: (1) I'm using 24-bit 8:8:8 color. I'm using `QEMU` as a sort of temporary solution, it would be cool if in the future I could get my code running on some real hardware. I don't know a lot about the details of how I'm using `QEMU`. (2) I'll try that! (3) I get what you mean, though (as I'm sure you've guessed based off my clueless series of posts) I'm not sure how I would go about doing that. (4) I'll be sure to look through that! Thanks for the help!

Comment: **UPDATE**: I both flipped `ax=4f02` with `ax=4f01` and changed the `mov edi, eax` to `lea edi, modeInfo`, though sadly nothing seems to have changed. Perhaps it really is just a `QEMU` issue.

Comment: You could show the _minimal_ code for VGA which just fills the screen with single color, which I gather you can make work. Then show the changes you do to make it use SVGA instead (which, I gather doesn't work).

Comment: @hyde To use `VESA`, a lot of code had to be changed and lot had to be added. I'll append the function to draw a pixel in `VGA` mode to the post.

Comment: Just as a head's-up regarding live hardware: the current design you are using, based on what is known as the 'legacy BIOS', won't run on most hardware released after 2019. Most newer PC motherboards use a UEFI BIOS, and many if not most have dropped support for the legacy mode. If you find an older PC, all good, but don't expect it to boot a newer one live. Note that this doesn't mean you shouldn't continue with this design (you can learn a lot about OS design from it), just be aware that newer UEFI systems won't work with it.

Comment: @Schol-R-LEA Thanks for the tip! I’m planning on running it on an old Optiplex 7020, so it should be good